# jQuery change default radio button value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the radio button that originally had `checked` against it by default and reset the value of it.

In the example below the value is already set to

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="test" value="0" checked>
<input type="radio" name="test" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="test" value="2">
```

I am using this to select the empty value, but how can I set it to empty first before selecting it?

```
$('input[name="test"][value=""]').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: do you mean you want to select the first radio button that value is empty? OR
do you mean you want to select the first radio button and then set its value to empty?

Comment: I want to select the first radio button and set its value to empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the `checked` input using `$('input[name="test"][checked]')` and update its value with `.val("")`

```js
const checkedInput = $('input[name="test"][checked]');
checkedInput.val("");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="test" value="0" checked>
<input type="radio" name="test" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="test" value="2">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make an .each on inputs and check if value is empty example:

```
$('input[name="test"]').each(function() {
     if($(this).val() === '') {
          //do something
     }
});
```